# Inserting multiple values from a select query into one JTable column in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I need to select the job titles that an employee has had from Mysql and put them into one Jtable column placed on a JFrame in Java but i couldn't find out the query. Here is the one that doesn't do the job:

```
 SELECT employeId, CONCAT(jobTitle)  FROM job;
```

And here is the table i am selecting from:

```
job( jobId, jobTitle, employeId );
```

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question and put more code ?

Comment: can u add the schema of the `job` table?

Comment: you can easily do a regular select and concat the job titles in java code

Comment: look into GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select employeId, GROUP_CONCAT(jobTitle) from job group by employeId
```